# How to tile under a cabinet?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, tile

I removed an old bathroom vanity and saw they didn’t tile under it. I have a new bathroom vanity that has legs and isn’t tight to the floor. What should I do? I found the same tile, should I break out the partial pieces of tile and tile the area? If so how do I do that on the unfinished wood?

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] in a picture that more clearly shows the edges of the tile at the floor?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Have you looked into how tile is set? Do you have spare tile? What specific challenge are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

Note that a classic cheat is to install just enough tile to get to or past the edges of the vanity, then add baseboards to cover the gap so people can't see the untiled section. Out of sight, out of mind, good enough for government work.

Comment: This is what I'd do if it was my bathroom. Vanities with legs are annoying - depending on the height of the legs it can be difficult or impossible to clean under it.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the grout around the tiles that you want to replace,  Use a sharp pointy tool, maybe a screwdriver and keep scratching it.

Then use something flat and scoop up the tiles carefully. Often people use a spade.  You might want something smaller for the delicate job that you need to do.  Use a jerky motion and try to remove them.

There is a chance that you may break unwanted ones, so ensure that you have a few spares.

Or, just make a feature out of it and

- place the matching tiles in a diagonal fashion
- or get different coloured tiles

Comment: A grout saw is a thing, when you want to remove grout. Not even that expensive.

Comment: But if you just remove the tiles, it should be fairly facile to remove the grout left behind—no saw needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the tiles were laid directly on the OSB.  Not the best practice, but you can place your new tile on the OSB just as the old since it will not be subject to foot traffic.

Scrape or grind out the grout as said by Rohit Gupta, and place the tiles. Be sure to protect the copper pipe, as the thinset will corrode the copper. It looks as if you will need to extend the baseboard as well.

Comment: Picture is not the best angle for being certain, but there might be CBU showing there in the side of the opening towards the toilet, actually. If so, that should be matched.